# How to run Scrapy-spider from crontab?

Tags: linux, cron, python-venv

I'm trying to set a task to run a script from such a sh-file (run_a.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/userdir
source venvProject/bin/activate
cd /home/userdir/scrapy_project
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl my_spider
```

My crontab string looks like this:
*/5 * * * * sh /home/userdir/run_a.sh

but it don't works, whats wrong?

Comment: Can you redirect the output of this cron task to a log, then post the log? E.g. change your cron specification to `*/5 * * * * sh /home/userdir/run_a.sh > /home/userdir/scrape.log 2>&1`

Comment: Also, you specify that the script should be run using bash in the first line of your script, but you run it using sh, which is a shell with fewer features. That looks like a bug. I'd suggest marking your script as executable (`chmod u+x run_a.sh`) and changing the command from `sh /home/userdir/run_a.sh` to `/home/userdir/run_a.sh`. That way your script will run using bash.

Comment: /home/userdir/run_a.sh: 3: source: not found
/home/userdir/run_a.sh: 7: scrapy: not found

Comment: chmod u+x run_a.sh + /home/userdir/run_a.sh  it works, thanks!